# How to use Word2Vec model inside foreachRDD in stateful (Checkpoint enabled) Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I have trained my Word2VecModel in batch processing, and using the same in Spark Streaming. So, I'm loading my model using `Word2VecModel.load(sc, Path)`.

In my Spark Streaming application, I'm using `groupByKeyAndWindow()`, which means I have to do checkpoint enabled stream processing on my `inputDStream`, and after that I want to use `findSynonyms()` from Word2VecModel inside `foreachRDD`.

I'm getting the following error:

> DStream checkpointing has been enabled but the DStreams with their functions are not serializable

I know what's the meaning of this error and why it's coming, the problem is I can't able to find the workaround.

Comment: I'm able to use findSynonyms() from Word2VecModel inside foreachRDD by loading the model inside the foreachRDD block, but the downside is for each batch, I'm loading it again and again, thus increasing the processing time.